# Nice way to force user fill varargs parameter in Java

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I want to force the user to fill in an optional parameter when calling my constructor:

```
public MyClass(String... params) {
    this.params = params;
}
```

Currently, the following code is valid:

```
new MyClass();
```

I want to prevent it. I thought of this:

```
public MyClass(String param1, String... otherParams) {
    this.params = new String[1 + otherParams.length];
    this.params[0] = param1;
    // fill 1..N params from otherParams
}
```

`String[] params` is not an option, because I need the ability to use comma separated args.

Are there any nice solutions to achieve this? Please don't say that varargs parameters must be optional. The question is not about that.

Comment: otherParams could be null if someone writes ´new MyClass("a", null)´

Comment: Could you just throw an exception if the number of arguments you expect isn't there?

Comment: Maybe check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751746/requiring-at-least-one-element-in-java-variable-argument-list) solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe the following, an extra default constructor?

```
/**
 * Please provide at least one parameter.
 */
@Deprecated
public MyClass() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Please provide at least one parameter");
}
```

Comment: @Tom I was too lazy & unknowing whether that would work. Thought about it.

Comment: @Tom if modifier will be private, new MyClass() would call varargs constructor -> fail

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Right ... too bad.

Comment: With public and deprecated my NetBeans IDE gives a strike-through on the no-params call, and that calls the default constructor.

Answer (score 8):

No, there's no other way to do this at compile-time. What you found is the usual pattern of forcing the client code to pass at least one parameter.

You can read it like this:

```
// You can pass in some parameters if you want
public MyClass(String... params)
```

and

```
// I require one parameter, you can pass some additional if you want
public MyClass(String param1, String... otherParams)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want do it at compile time you need it to do as you suggested in your last code example.

Then you can use the ApacheCommons - [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T[],%20T...%29) class:

```
String[] allParams = ArrayUtils.add(otherParams, 0, param1); //Insert the first param at the first position of the array.
```

Answer (score 1):

Throw a IllegalArgumentException if the caller did not supply a non-empty parameter array.

EDIT: paraphrased the original text as answer

Comment: Because it is much better to check such conditions during compilation. Btw Questions -> Comment.

Comment: ...for the price of a temporary array creation. btw the comment was added at the same time as my answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JNYRanger: formally it is a comment, but actually it is a solution to the question how to force a user to provide a non-empty var-arg parameter.

Comment: @wero I'd recommend that you'd reword it then to sound more like an answer than a comment & explain the reasoning behind it.